# Generalised itemset mining?

Tags: data-mining, pattern-recognition

As far as I understand, the common approaches to itemset mining assume the following:

- An itemset is a conjunctive logical clause (which in some approaches allow negation)
- All items are in principle logically independent (e.g. if A is in the itemset, we do not a-priori exclude the possibility of B being in there)

I would be interested in more general unsupervised pattern mining algorithm, which in addition to conjunction and negation also allows disjunction (think propositional logic). Also, there might be known logical dependencies  between the items, e.g., if A is included, B is also always included (or cannot be included) etc. In a nutshell, my data consists of items, where each item is described with a vector of binary features (some of the features logically depend on others) and I am interested in finding patterns such as:

```
A AND (B OR NOT C)
```

which occur more frequent (or less frequent) than expected.

I looked around for some time, but was not able to find any literature on this. I hope that someone could point me to a paper or two or give me a few keywords that I could look at?

Comment: Do you have a real use case for this? See: when analyzing shopping behavior, you do not know *why* a user did not buy an item. Maybe he didn't like it; but maybe he also did not know it, it wasn't available or too expensive. Unless you can discern such situations, there is little information to be gained from negative information, because there is "more than one negative" that you cannot distinguish.

Comment: I do actually :) I am not interested in shopping behaviour, I am looking for probabilistic grammar patterns in natural languages. My data points are descriptions of certain expressions in language corpora, and each description is a set of binary features. This makes the setup quite similar to the itemset mining (of course, the logical dependencies between the features make it more complex). As to the patterns: negation is less of an issue, it can be represented as a 'positive' feature anyway. However, disjunction is very important — the algorithm needs to be able to detect classes of features.

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this? I am working on something related and also not finding a lot.

Comment: I ended up developing my own algorithm. It uses the inclusion-exclusion principle with a number of heuristics and optimisations to correctly compute the probabilities under the null hypothesis (independence assumptions). It is not particularly fast and it won't be able to cope with large network features, but it works reasonably well for my purpose. And having access to a Cray XC40 surely doesn't hurt here :p I will certainly publish the algorithm at some point, but it will take time. However, we could work something out between us in the meantime if you are interested.

Comment: I am also working on something similar and would be interested in your approach. Did you publish anything yet? Would you mind sharing your algorithm with me, I'd also be interested in contributing.